# Get coordinate from mouse click in ArcMap using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I am using ArcObjects C# tool in ArcGIS that identifies map coordinates when a user clicks on a location within a map. Here's the code that I have used:

[image]

My map use units of Meters so the tool displays the Meters coordinates. How can I have this tool return degrees decimal?

Comment: Please include code as text rather than pictures so that it is available for future searches and to copy/paste for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your maps spatial reference is a well defined spatial reference it should 'know' its compatible geographic coordinate system.. cast to [IProjectedCoordinateSystem](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IProjectedCoordinateSystem_Interface/002m000002qv000000/) then obtain the [GeographicCoordinateSystem](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001qp000000) and project the point:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs arg)
{
    IMxDocument pMxDoc = ArcMap.Document;
    IPoint pPoint = pMxDoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y);
    // so far so good.. but the point is in the FocusMap spatial reference

    // set the spatial reference on the point
    pPoint.SpatialReference = pMxDoc.FocusMap.SpatialReference;

    // if it is 'well defined' it should be either IGeographicCoordinateSystem or IProjectedCoordinateSystem
    // and not IUnknownCoordinateSystem. If it is already geographic then there's nothing to do, if projected
    // then project the point to its parent geographic coordinate system
    if (pMxDoc.FocusMap.SpatialReference is IProjectedCoordinateSystem)
    {
        IProjectedCoordinateSystem pProjSR = (IProjectedCoordinateSystem)pMxDoc.FocusMap.SpatialReference;
        IGeographicCoordinateSystem pGeoSR = pProjSR.GeographicCoordinateSystem;
        pPoint.Project((ISpatialReference)pGeoSR);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Map X: " + pPoint.X + "\nMap Y: " + pPoint.Y);
}
```